# How do I display an error message if the input is wrong on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

*Im trying to display an error message in RED beside the input field to let the user know, however I dont know why my error message is not working. The requirement for the input is starting with a capital letter, followed by non special characters (any alphabets) please help me see what is wrong with my code*

*I am still new to HTML and I know many people said about regex but im not sure i have not learn that*

```
<html>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value; 
    if (/^[A-Z]\D{2,30}$/.test(fname) == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("errorName").innerHTML = "Your email must be filled"; 
        return false;
    {
    return name;
}
</script>

<style>
#errorName 
{
    color:red; 
}
</style>
<form action="handleServer.php" method="get" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
    <body>
        <!-- starting with first name--> 
        First name: </br>
        <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" size="30"> 
        <span id="errorName"></br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </body>
</form> 
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, first notice that the `if` statement is not correctly closed (and it's the reason because code gives an error in console), also consider to include `form` tag inside `body` one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your if statements are not closed properly and also the input box.

Please find [codepan](https://codepen.io/kushalraid/pen/rNLLGoy?editors=1111)

```
    function validateForm() {
  console.log(1);
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value; 
    if (/^[A-Z]\D{2,30}$/.test(fname) == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("errorName").innerHTML = "Your email must be filled"; 
        return false;
    {
    return name;
}
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please approve my answer if it is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

When i tend to use regex i store it in its own value like this:

```
const patternName = /[0-9]|[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/|#]/;
let resultName = patternName.test(name.value);
```

The code above checks if the `name` contains anything from the regex above and if it does `resultName` will return `true`.

Next we can do the following:

1. If `name` is empty you get an error and it contains anything from the regex above we. In this case we show the error
2. If `resultName` is `true` we know that `name` contains something from the regex, so that it's not a valid name.
3. If not we show success message

```
if (name.value === "" || resultName) {
    showErrorName();
} else {
    showSuccessName();
}`
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question, but anyway, it would be better to put explanation into simple text in your answer rather than comments in the code snippet, which is a bit hard to read.

Comment: oh wow!! this is another way as well, thank you! :)

Comment: I will try to do better answers :) im new to StackOverflow so im learning